# Where are Google chrome passwords stored in windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, passwords, sql, sqlite

I know that Google Chrome stores the login data at **LocalAppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data** but this doesn't shows the password, password value shows as the single special character. 
I want to read the password value from the database.
I want to make an utility which can store the users sign on data in a backup file for user.

Comment: The passwords are not stored in plain text.

Comment: @Ramhound May i get the path as I'm unable to see the encrypted password even.

Comment: The file you're referring to is a database – SQLite3, to be specific. Still, passwords won't be saved in an easily reversible encryption. Since they are encrypted and decrypted locally, it might be possible to manually decrypt them, but don't get your hopes up.

Comment: I read that chrome passwords are encrypted by using the windows method
**CryptProtectData function (Windows)** is there any way to decrypt this password.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thank you very much to all of you, I got the ans. one can decrypt the chrome passwords by using windows API **CryptUnprotectData**.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//superuser.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 7):

Chrome passwords are stored in sqllite database but passwords are encrypted using  **CryptProtectData**, which is a Windows API function for encrypting data. Data encrypted with this function is pretty solid. It can only be decrypted on the same machine and by the same user that encrypted it in the first place.

If you want to decrypt password you must do it using same machine which encryption done.

There is a app called ChromePasswordDump, which can decrypt passwords using that application, that can be easily Googled.

Comment: thank u Nicole,can you give me the example of decryption of data.