# Chrome sync accidentally deleted almost all my passwords. How can I upload them again from an old profile?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, sync

I started an old version of chrome. One I didn’t use for years (let´s say it was on an old Windows).
It did say `syncing is suspend`. I choose to reenable again and now https://passwords.google.com only contains the 3 passwords I had 4 years ago (whereas I normally have several hundred passwords recorded on https://passwords.google.com).

Fortunately, I’ve a Linux install which I used yesterday which still contains all the passwords previously being synced.

How I can use that profile to put the passwords back to https://passwords.google.com without risking that syncing deletes the passwords on that local copy (besides backing up the profile on disk)?

Comment: I assume you have not started that Chrome installation since yesterday, so you have not repeated the steps you did, and resume the synchronization?  I would of course clone the Chrome user profile directory no matter what you try.

Comment: @Ramhound I started it just to check but with the Ethernet Cable unplugged.

Comment: Do you have a password export and password import on the  *chrome://flags* page?

Comment: @Ramhound only password import. It’s Chrome 76.

Comment: In *chrome://settings/passwords* I can, next to "Saved Passwords", click the three dots and get a menu that offers Import and Export. You could perhaps export from the old profile while disconnected from the internet to avoid sync, then import it to the new profile while connected.

Comment: Chrome is not my main browser, but it seems strange that import while sync is on does not update the account sooner or later. It might be taking time because of encryption so be patient. You might need to enable *chrome://flags/#PasswordImport*.

Comment: @harrymc I think the import mechanism is simply not linked with the online sync. And in my case on the 3 dots I now have only to option for exporting not import (because I accidentally updated it to version 86 through `apt-get upgrade`).

Comment: My Chrome is up to date on version 80 and `#PasswordImport` works to enable Import.

Comment: Assuming this is Windows, try the locally cached location here and try to restore the data from an old copy if you have it: https://superuser.com/questions/718383/where-are-google-chrome-passwords-stored-in-windows

Comment: You may also try `chrome.exe -enable-features=PasswordImport`. Try also "Use DevTools to Unhide Import option" in [this article](https://www.guidingtech.com/import-passwords-csv-google-chrome/). After import, leave Chrome running for a long time.

Comment: @harrymc no longer in chrome flags unfortunately.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 I’m on Linux. The problem isn’t copying the passwords to another local install but putting them online again.

Comment: You could downgrade Chrome to my version 80, where import still works.

Comment: @harrymc Chrome installs from it’s Google Server. I tried an old installer and it complains it can’t download what’s required. I think dealing with the api directly is the required answer as I got the api key used by Google Chrome. The problem is I didn’t found the documentation for that part (which server requests to do).

Comment: You only need the current stable version 80, nothing older.

Comment: It's quite scary to know that synced passwords can be removed so easily. Google Password should've at least provide the option to restore recently deleted passwords to avoid bad actors from clearing out saved passwords from our devices. Be it from laptops or mobiles we left unlocked or accidental deletion as described above.